# Converting String to date format to add to string arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, simpledateformat

I Get the following Date from my SQLite database which get pulled down as a string in the following format '03-07-2015'.

I want this format to display like this 'Fri 3rd July 2015' I am doing this using SimpleDateFormat, I then need to pass this into an ArrayList, I cannot quite get this to work, any advice to what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

```
String dayNumberSuffix = getDayOfMonthSuffix(3);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd'" + dayNumberSuffix + "' MMMM yyyy");
String d = sdf.format(cursor.getString(1));
dates.add(d); // ArrayList<String>

String getDayOfMonthSuffix(final int n) {
    switch (n % 10) {
        case 1:  return "st";
        case 2:  return "nd";
        case 3:  return "rd";
        default: return "th";
    }
}
```

I have tried a few different variations, but I believe the one above is closest.

Comment: Whats the result of the method you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to parse the date in the parse `03-07-2015`, that you get from your database and format it:

```
String dayNumberSuffix = getDayOfMonthSuffix(3);
SimpleDateFormat parseSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd'" + dayNumberSuffix + "' MMMM yyyy");
Date date = parseSDF.parse(cursor.getString(1));
String d = sdf.format(date);
dates.add(d); // ArrayList<String>
```

should do it